# Angular not displaying data received from http response

Tags: java, html, angular, typescript, spring-boot

I have a Service type script class as follows:

```
export class HomeApiService{

apiURL = 'http://localhost:8080/api';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getProfileData():Observable<HomeModelInterface[]>{
        return this.http.get<HomeModelInterface[]>(this.apiURL+'/home');}
}
```

I have component class as follows:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

public profileData: HomeModelInterface[] | undefined ;

constructor(private homeApiService:HomeApiService) { }

ngOnInit() {
 this.homeApiService.getProfileData().subscribe(data=> {
   this.profileData = data;
   console.log(this.profileData);
});
}
```

I have html file as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let profile of profileData">
 <h1>{{profile.data}}</h1>
</div>
```

Here is the backend spring boot application controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/home" , method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = 
  "application/json")
 public Object getHome() {
    ResponseHome response = new ResponseHome();
    response.setData(new String[]{"Greetings from Spring Boot API home!", 
  HttpStatus.ACCEPTED.toString()});
    return response;
   }
```

Here is my ResponseHome java class:

```
public class ResponseHome {

private String data[];
private String errors[];

public String[] getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String[] data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String[] getErrors() {
    return errors;
}

public void setErrors(String[] errors) {
    this.errors = errors;
}
}
```

Here is my frontend model typescript class to parse that json to a model class:

```
export interface HomeModelInterface{
data: string[];
errors: string[];
}
```

When i run it chrome i see the following error:
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'
[image: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object']

Can you please help?

Comment: The response is a singular entity, a single object and you are trying to run a for loop on it. You need to use it directly `{{profileData.data}}`

Comment: If you take a look at service class i am returning array of HomeModelInterface 
getProfileData():Observable<HomeModelInterface[]>{
        return this.http.get<HomeModelInterface[]>(this.apiURL+'/home');}

Comment: Your response returns a single instance of `HomeModelInterface` with an array `data[]`, so instead of using `HomeModelInterface[]`, use `HomeModelInterface` and loop over `model.data[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is an object not an array. In order to iterate, you should get the list that's in it. Try something like profileData.data in *ngFor.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).